# how to assign different name for each textbox in a loop in php

Tags: php

Can anyone let me know how to assign different names for each textbox in loop in php for the following code..

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql )){ 
    print "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td><td> <input type=text name=obtmarks</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter nice and simple:

```
$i=0;
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) 
{ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td>
        <td>".$data['name'] . " </td>
        <td> <input type='text' name='obtmarks_".$i."'></td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Note: I also corrected your open/close brackets and put quotes where they needed to go inside the elements.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Why thank you, but seriously, if we keep upvoting like this, people will start to talk lol.

Comment: Talk about what? Every one from here posted a bad code. I had to modify their answers. :)

Comment: tanq...how to read the values of those text boxes..in the nxt page.. ??

Comment: @Nandu You can use them in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array and do a `foreach` statement or whatever other method tickles your fancy to iterate back through them.

Comment: In the next page i have to insert the entire data into another table using the same loop.. how to read the values of those textboxes in that case..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create form elements that are in an array.

This is [documented at php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

```
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
```

Thus, you could perhaps use:

```
$fmt = "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>input type='text' name='obtmarks[]'></td></tr>\n";

?><table><tr><th>ID</td><th>Name</th></tr><?php

while ( $data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
    printf($fmt, $data['idno'], $data['name']);
}

?></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
{
    Print "<tr><td>{$data['idno']}</td><td>{$data['name']}</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"obtmarks{$i++}\"/></td></tr>";
}
```

Keep your code clean and readable. Make proper use of "",{} and ''.

Edit:

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
    {
        Print "<tr><td>{$data['idno']}</td><td>{$data['name']}</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"obtmarks[]\"/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"obtmarks_id[]\" value=\"{$data['idno']}\"/></td></tr>";
    }
```

And then on second page you will have 2 arrays waiting in $_POST, obtmarks[] containing user input and obtmarks_id[] containing corresponding ID's

```
    $obtmarks = $_POST['obtmarks[]'];
    $obtmarks_id = $_POST['obtmarks_id[]'];

    foreach($obtmarks as $k => $v) {
        // PSEUDO SQL: INSERT $v .... WHERE id=$obtmarks_id[$k]
    }
```

Comment: Tanq.. But In the next page i have to insert the entire data into another table using the same loop.. how to read the values of those textboxes in that case..

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter what the name is, you can do something as simple as this:

```
$counter = 0;
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) 
 { 
    print "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td><td> <input type='text' name='obtmarks{$counter}' /></td></tr>";
    $counter += 1;
 }
```

Comment: Tanq.. But In the next page i have to insert the entire data into another table using the same loop.. how to read the values of those textboxes in that case..

Answer (score 0):

`<input type=text name=" .$variable." /></td></tr>"` $variable could come from the mysql TABLE, field having different values or you may use a counter as the answers below.